# Spacing inside a function with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I tend to leave 1 line of space after the declaration of a (PHP) function and before closing it.

```
function foo($bar) {
  [empty line]
  do_the_things();
  return $something;
  [empty line]
}
```

To me it seems clearer to read.

But I don't notice many other people doing that and I guess it uglies up my code for other people.

I wonder if there's a way to get my editor to just identify the function declaration *"function foo($bar) {"* and just visually leave 10px margin below that line and then look for the closing *"}"* and leave 10px margin above it? Sort of like syntax highlighting, but instead of highlighting it would pad it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from build 3118, Sublime Text has a feature called Phantoms, which can be used to insert inline HTML content inside the buffers. We can write a plugin to use this feature to create the padding you desire. (There is no other way to do it, as color schemes can't change the font size etc. and the `line_padding_top`/`line_padding_bottom` preferences affect all lines.)

- Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
- Replace the template with the following:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class FunctionSpacer(sublime_plugin.ViewEventListener):
    @classmethod
    def is_applicable(cls, settings):
        return settings is not None and '/PHP/' in settings.get('syntax', '')

    spacing = None

    def __init__(self, view):
        super().__init__(view)
        self.spacing = sublime.PhantomSet(view)
        self.on_modified_async()

    def on_modified_async(self):
        regions = list()

        # find all function names and braces
        potential_spacing_locations = self.view.find_by_selector('entity.name.function, punctuation.section.block')
        depth = -1
        for region in potential_spacing_locations:
            if self.view.match_selector(region.begin(), 'entity.name.function'):
                regions.append(region)
                depth = 0
            elif depth != -1:
                for pos in range(region.begin(), region.end()):
                    if self.view.match_selector(pos, 'punctuation.section.block.begin') and depth != -1:
                        depth += 1
                    elif self.view.match_selector(pos, 'punctuation.section.block.end'):
                        depth -= 1
                        if depth == 0:
                            row, col = self.view.rowcol(region.begin())
                            regions.append(sublime.Region(self.view.text_point(row - 1, col)))
                            depth = -1

        phantoms = [sublime.Phantom(region, '<br style="font-size: 10pt" />', sublime.LAYOUT_BELOW) for region in regions]
        self.spacing.update(phantoms)
```

- Save it in the folder ST suggests, as `function_spacing.py`

How it works:

- when the syntax is set to PHP and the buffer is modified (or the plugin is first loaded), it finds all function definitions in the file and goes through them one by one:
- it adds a Phantom below the function definition
- it then goes through all the relevant curly braces to determine where the function ends, and adds a Phantom to the line above the curly brace that closes the function

Because it works on the syntax highlighting engine it is very efficient and doesn't have to re-implement any of the same logic like ignoring braces in strings or comments etc.

Comment: This is half correct. However, spacing is added *prior* to both curly brackets. The formatting desired by the OP entailed spacing *after* the opening bracket, and *before* the closing bracket, not prior on both.